# Angular Directive with bootstrap popover not working in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been stuck at Angular directive not working ng-repeat.

The requirement is on hover of the text, a popover should appear. The popover has a link, when the user clicks the link it opens in new tab.

I have created the popover which has a link and also opens up in new tab. But when used with ng-repeat the popover it works only on 1st record and not on any other records.

I am posting the code with which I am facing the issue.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in records">
  <label>{{x.Name}}</label>
  ::::::::
  <label>{{x.Country}}</label>
  <popup-directive></popup-directive>
</div>
```

Script.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'directives']);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.records = [
   {
        "Name" : "Sumit",
        "Country" : "Germany"
    },{
        "Name" : "Akki",
        "Country" : "Sweden"
    },{
        "Name" : "Ashwin",
        "Country" : "Mexico"
    },{
        "Name" : "Sid",
        "Country" : "Austria"
    }
]
});

var directives = angular.module('directives', []);
directives.directive('popupDirective', function($compile,$window) {
return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    template: "<a id='pop-over-link''>Show pop-over</a>" +
              "<div id='pop-over-content' style='display:none'><button       class='btn btn-primary' ng-click='testFunction()'>Ok</button></div>",
    link: function(scope, elements, attrs) {
        $("#pop-over-link").popover({
            'placement': 'bottom',
            'trigger': 'hover focus',
            'html': true,
            'delay':{hide:5000},
            'content': function() {
                return $compile($("#pop-over-content").html())(scope);
            }
        },1000);

        scope.testFunction = function() {
            $window.open('https://www.google.com','_blank');
        }

    }
}
});
```

Comment: Not sure why you're using jQuery, why you're compiling templates, etc. But given that you're looking for an element identified by pop-over-content, and given that an ID is supposed to be unique in a document, that can't possibly work. Why don't you use angular-ui-bootstrap, which supports popovers?

Comment: Use angular ui bootstrap popover

Comment: @JB Nizet,@ Rahul -- i have tried angular-ui-bootstrap, which has 3 flavours i,e uib-popover, uib-popover-html, uib-popover-template. But i need to have a link in popover content which can be opened in new tab.

Comment: So? That leaves two possible flavours.

Comment: @JB Nizet, could you please suggest them

Comment: Well, a link is an HTML element. So you can't use a uib-popover, which expects plain text. Read the documentation. Look at the examples. Try something.

Comment: @JB Nizet, well i tried them, but none is letting me call a function to open link in new tab.

Comment: The  you did something wrong: https://plnkr.co/edit/yFBOz3NP5EQQ0Qyyd2SB?p=preview

Comment: @JB Nizet, got it. Thanks for the help mate.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.directive('popupDirective', function ($compile, $window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        template: "<a class='pop-over-link''>Show pop-over</a>" +
                  "<div id='pop-over-content' style='display:none'><button       class='btn btn-primary' ng-click='testFunction()'>Ok</button></div>",
        link: function (scope, elements, attrs) {
            $(".pop-over-link").popover({
                'placement': 'bottom',
                'trigger': 'hover focus',
                'html': true,
                'delay': { hide: 5000 },
                'content': function () {
                    return $compile($("#pop-over-content").html())(scope);
                }
            }, 1000);

            scope.testFunction = function () {
                $window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');
            }

        }
    }
});
```